# Ubuntu 22.04.2LTS HDMI to TV [almost] No Sound

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, pulseaudio, hdmi

I recently installed 22.04.2, dual boot with Windows 10 on my laptop [HP 250 G6 Notebook, I5 2,5Ghz, 8GB RAM] - HDMI connection to a Samsung TV. This works fine with Windows but not Ubuntu. I've tried all the solutions from various sites including from this one e.g. GRUB entry modified to include:

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="intel_iommu=on,igfx_off"

When I use the Pulseaudio pavucontrol app I can select the PC speakers options and it is playing back OK. When I select the HDMI option the sound is active but to out put.

After much experimenting what is really strange now is the following:

1] I select the [non HDMI] digital sound option and play a .avi video. Sound from PC speakers.

2] Now I change, via pulseaudio, to the first HDMI option and the sound comes via HDMI on the TV. I can open a Youtube vid, for example, and the sound is fine via TV HDMI. As soon as I close it and go to something else - music file for example, the sound no longer works on the TV whilst the indicator on pusleaudio bar says it is working.

***It is as though playing a xxx.avi video file via HDMI opens a connection temporarily and then shuts it off after the current session closes.***

Does anyone have any idea how this can be fixed please?